# Use array of ID's obtained from hrefs to target elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm having trouble why the below code isn't working as intended. I'm trying to obtain an array of ID's on the page from a content table, by saving the anchor tags `href` to the array. The array is constructed as I would have expected, but when I try to use it as the targeted element, nothing happens. I suspect that it's because the array is transformed into a string (which it would also seem from the console.log), but I still don't quite understand why it won't work. Do I have to transform the array into objects, and if so, how is that done? I haven't been able to find anything meeningful to me anywhere.

**Edit:** I have to do it this way (preferably at least) as the content table is meant to be created dynamically (not the same elements at all times), and the elements which the content table is pointing to should be styled accordingly.

```js
var elements = [];
$(".bb").each(function() {
  elements.push($(this).attr("href"));
});
console.log(elements);

$(elements).each(function() {
  $(this).css("background", "red");
});

// This works for a single elment, however
var el = $(".cc").attr("href");
$(el).css("background", "green");
```

```css
 body {
  padding-bottom: 100px;
 }
div {
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background: #d3fcff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="aa"></div>
<div id="xx"></div>

<a class="bb" href="#aa">target #aa</a>
<a class="bb" href="#xx">target #xx</a>

<p>Not using an array and targeting a single element works however</p>
<div id="zz"></div>
<a class="cc" href="#zz">target #zz</a>
```

Comment: You problem is that there is no jQuery way to convert "array of selectors" into "array of jQuery element wrappers". You would need to convert the id list into a single string with comma separators: `$(elements.join(';'))`. See [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var elements = [];
$(".bb").each(function() {
  elements.push($(this).attr("href"));
});
console.log(elements);



$.each(elements, function(i,val) {


  $(val).css("background", "red");
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background:#fff9d3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="aa"></div>
<div id="xx"></div>

<a class="bb" href="#aa">target #aa</a>
<a class="bb" href="#xx">target #xx</a>

<p>Not using an array and targeting a single element works however</p>
<div id="zz"></div>
<a class="cc" href="#zz">target #zz</a>
```

Since you want to get elements of array you have created, not dom elements/objects, you can use:

```
$.each(elements, function(i,val) {


  $(val).css("background", "red");
});
```

By `$(val)` - you create jQuery object, and your script will work.

Notice difference: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/  and http://api.jquery.com/each/

Answer (score 1):

Your array contains the hrefs that you want to target - therefore they must be used in the selector as follows - select all `a`'s with the `hrefs` in the array -

```js
var elements = [];
$(".bb").each(function() {
  elements.push($(this).attr("href"));
});
console.log(elements);

elements.forEach(function(element) {
  $('a[href='+element+']').css("background", "red");
});

// This works for a single elment, however
var el = $(".cc").attr("href");
$(el).css("background", "green");
```

```css
body {
  padding-bottom: 100px;
 }
div {
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background: #d3fcff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="aa"></div>
<div id="xx"></div>

<a class="bb" href="#aa">target #aa</a>
<a class="bb" href="#xx">target #xx</a>

<p>Not using an array and targeting a single element works however</p>
<div id="zz"></div>
<a class="cc" href="#zz">target #zz</a>
```

Comment: It works! Excellent. However, I wish to target the div's with the `.css()` and not the anchor tags. The following inside the `elements.forEach()`works for that matter: `$(element).css("background", "red");`. However, would you care to ellaborate why this actually works as opposed to my own attempt? :)

Comment: Glad it works - the reason why is that my version iterates over the declared array ("elements') - whereas yours was trying to iterate over an undeclared element  - "$(elements)". Also the use of the href in the selector allows the a's with the specified href to be targetted. I still think there is a better way of doing this. And also - I would rather have a statically defined class "(.red) with a designated style rule (.red {background: red} ) and then apply that class to the a's... I always prefer to keep my style rules int he CSS instead of dynamically added to the element. But thats just me